# How check apache & php-fpm config is appropriate (not too high or too low)

Tags: php, performance, apache, high-availability

I will have an event with 3k users on an app (php base).

I launch several instances in the cloud and install LAMP on it.[*to make load test and choose on for the event*]

**On Ubuntu 18**

[image]

I enable mpm_event and php7.4-fpm, (*which seems to be the better configuration for high traffic with apache and php app*).

I use [this post](https://medium.com/@sbuckpesch/apache2-and-php-fpm-performance-optimization-step-by-step-guide-1bfecf161534) which explain how tune your conf.
Like this :

Here apache2 mpm event conf :

```
<IfModule mpm_*_module>
  ServerLimit           (Total RAM - Memory used for Linux, DB, etc.) / process size
  StartServers          (Number of Cores)
  MinSpareThreads       25
  MaxSpareThreads       75
  ThreadLimit           64
  ThreadsPerChild       25
  MaxRequestWorkers     (Total RAM - Memory used for Linux, DB, etc.) / process size
  MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

Here php7.4-fpm :

```
pm = dynamic            
pm.max_children         (total RAM - (DB etc) / process size)
pm.start_servers        (cpu cores * 4)
pm.min_spare_servers    (cpu cores * 2)
pm.max_spare_servers    (cpu cores * 4)
pm.max_requests         1000
```

**My goal is** : even if I rely of these method, I would saw some metric like :

- *--> You have too many thread (from apache worker or from phpfpm) unused open*
- *--> All your thread (from apache worker or from phpfpm) are already busy and use*

I already test: htop, glance, vmstat, sar to check io, cpu, ram but even with that it's not clear to me :
**Does my configuration is good for this machine with this load or should I increase/decrease something?**
Then I could be sure these configuration are good and start other subject : CDN, cache ...

How do you manage this ?
thanks by advance,

Comment: Depends if the 3k users will send requests to the server simultaniously, like in a large conference room, or not, like when they interact with the server during the day. In the latter case, you do not need to worry.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, but my question is more related on the config test and how see if it's too much or not. No matter the event specificity.
In this particular case, we have a peak at the hour of event starting and then each user make request / 5sec to .

Comment: What is the test component giving you the messages "you have too many threads unused" ? Asking because it's worth checking the source code for the phrase "too many" and whether they even incude a scenario for "just right" or "too many" simply means "you have free threads". I've seen similar badly formatted messages before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, this depends on your script(s). We have this dynamically adjusted in our deploy scripts based on the server(s) being rolled up.

The following script is based on running Apache, on Centos, on AWS infrastructure but could easily be adapted to what you are using.

Basically:

- set the size of apache processes
- set the size of php process
- scripts gets available memory, cores and does some crunching and then modifies the config.
- we run this as part of stack roll up

Primary Source / Based on:

- https://medium.com/@sbuckpesch/apache2-and-php-fpm-performance-optimization-step-by-step-guide-1bfecf161534

Steps:

1. Calculate process size

You need to know how many processes can run on your machine. So calculate the process size of your main CPU/memory drivers is necessary.

```
cd /tmp
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py --output ps_mem.py
chmod a+x ps_mem.py
sudo python ps_mem.py
# Sample numbers:
# 28.4 MiB + 103.0 KiB = 28.5 MiB memcached
# 34.7 MiB + 9.5 KiB = 34.7 MiB amazon-cloudwatch-agent
# 24.8 MiB + 18.0 MiB = 42.8 MiB httpd (15)
# 69.1 MiB + 7.0 MiB = 76.0 MiB php (2)
# 228.2 MiB + 46.0 MiB = 274.3 MiB php-fpm (36)
```

Here you can see that there are 15 httpd processes, consuming a total of 43MiB, so each Apache process is using roughly 3MiB of RAM.
The php-fpm process will use about 7.6MiB.

2. Calculate Apache MaxRequestWorkers

To be safe though, reserve 15% of memory for all other processes (in my case ~1.2GiB) and round up apache process size to 3MiB.

```
MaxRequestWorkers = (Total RAM - Memory used for Linux, DB, etc.) / process size
MaxRequestWorkers = (8000MB - 1200MB) / 3MB = 2,266
```

3. Calculate php-fpm max-children

To be safe though, reserve 1 GiB for all other processes and round up php process size to 8MiB.

```
max_children = (Total RAM - Memory used for Linux, DB, etc.) / process size
max_children = (8000MB - 1200MB) / 8MB = 850
```

4. Here is the script we use, on roll up.

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> # Creates a configuration script to run once final servers are up.
> PROCESS_SIZE_APACHE_MB=3
> PROCESS_SIZE_PHP_MB=8
>
> # Get some values from the server
> MEMORY_KB=`grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '"'"'{print $2}'"'"'`
> MEMORY_MB=$(($MEMORY_KB / 1024))
> MEMORY_AVAILABLE_MB=$(($MEMORY_KB / 1178))
> NUM_CORES=`nproc --all`
> echo "Memory: $MEMORY_MB MB"
> echo "Memory Available: $MEMORY_AVAILABLE_MB MB"
> echo "Num Cores $NUM_CORES"
>
> #Now do some calculations
> SERVER_LIMIT=$(($MEMORY_AVAILABLE_MB / $PROCESS_SIZE_APACHE_MB))
> echo "HTTP MPM Server Limit: $SERVER_LIMIT"
>
> #Convert Apache from mpm-prefork to mpm-worker
> #Set params
> #<IfModule mpm_*_module>
> #  ServerLimit           (Total RAM - Memory used for Linux, DB, etc.) / process size
> #   StartServers          (Number of Cores)
> #   MinSpareThreads       25
> #   MaxSpareThreads       75
> #   ThreadLimit           64
> #   ThreadsPerChild       25
> #   MaxRequestWorkers     (Total RAM - Memory used for Linux, DB, etc.) / process  size
> #   MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
> # </IfModule>
> # /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf
>
> echo "
> # LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
> # LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
> LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
>
> <IfModule mpm_*_module>
>   ServerLimit           $SERVER_LIMIT
>   StartServers          $NUM_CORES
>   MinSpareThreads       25
>   MaxSpareThreads       75
>   ThreadLimit           64
>   ThreadsPerChild       25
>   MaxRequestWorkers     $SERVER_LIMIT
>   MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
> </IfModule>
> " > /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf
>
> # Configure the workers
> # pm = dynamic
> # pm.max_children         (total RAM - (DB etc) / process size) = 850
> # pm.start_servers        (cpu cores * 4)
> # pm.min_spare_servers    (cpu cores * 2)
> # pm.max_spare_servers    (cpu cores * 4)
> # pm.max_requests         1000
> MAX_CHILDREN=$(($MEMORY_AVAILABLE_MB / $PROCESS_SIZE_PHP_MB))
> echo "Max Children: $MAX_CHILDREN"
> NUM_START_SERVERS=$(($NUM_CORES * 4))
> NUM_MIN_SPARE_SERVERS=$(($NUM_CORES * 2))
> NUM_MAX_SPARE_SERVERS=$(($NUM_CORES * 4))
>
> sed -c -i "s/^;*pm.max_children.*/pm.max_children = $MAX_CHILDREN/" /etc/php- fpm.d/www.conf
> sed -c -i "s/^;*pm.start_servers.*/pm.start_servers = $NUM_START_SERVERS/" /etc/php- fpm.d/www.conf
> sed -c -i "s/^;*pm.min_spare_servers.*/pm.min_spare_servers =  $NUM_MIN_SPARE_SERVERS/" /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
> sed -c -i "s/^;*pm.max_spare_servers.*/pm.max_spare_servers =  $NUM_MAX_SPARE_SERVERS/" /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
> sed -c -i "s/^;*pm.max_requests = 500.*/pm.max_requests = 1000/" /etc/php-> fpm.d/www.conf
> ```

Comment: I was puzzled by the linked article as they seem to allocate the full 16GB of their server's RAM to *both* Apache *and* PHP. Your calculation has much more logically split the total into 8GB for each. However considering your average Apache process uses less than half a PHP process (3MB vs ~8MB), would it not make sense to split the 16GB in a ratio matching that, eg 1:2, so 5GB for Apache and 10GB for PHP (rounding for simplicity)?

Comment: Hmm - but now I see your script actually does the same as the article, and allocates the full `$MEMORY_AVAILABLE_MB` to **both** Apache and PHP, unlike your text which describes splitting it 50/50 ... ?

Comment: FYI, on an unrelated note - the article's `ServerLimit` recommendation is wildly incorrect.  [The Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) suggest it should be `MaxRequestWorkers / ThreadsPerChild`, definitely not the same as `MaxRequestWorkers`.  The comments on that medium article also discuss this.

Comment: That comment on the Medium article was written after this answer: it does suggest that (if not prefork) then additional maths is required. Everyone's solution may vary; currently the above works for me in a pretty dynamic environment  but feel free to adapt as needed.

Answer (score 2):

No tool will give you that kind of metric because the best configuration depends greatly on your php scripts. If you have 4 cores and each request consumes 100% of one core for 1 second, the server will handle 4 request per second in the best case regardless of your mpm and php configuration. The type of hardware you have is also important. Some CPUs perform multiple times better than others.

Since you are using php_fpm, the apache mpm configuration will have little effect on performance. You just need to make sure the server doesn't crash with too many requests and have more apache threads than php processes. Note that the RAM is not the only thing that can make a server unreachable. Trying to execute more process than the CPU can handle will increase the load and the number of context switches, decrease the CPU cache efficiency and result in even lower performance.

The ideal number of php processes depends on how your scripts use CPU and other resources. If each script uses 50% of the time with I/O operations for example, 2 processes per core may be ideal. Assuming that those I/O operations can be done in parallel without blocking each other.

You'll also need to take into account the amount of resources used by other processes such as the DB. SQL databases can easily use more resources than the php scripts themselves.

`Spare Servers` and `Spare Threads` are the number of processes/threads that can be idle waiting for work. Creating threads takes time, so it's better to have them ready when a request arrives. The downside is that those threads will consume resources such as RAM even when idle, so you'll want to keep just enough of them alive. Both apache and php_fpm will handle this automatically. The number of idle threads will be reduced and increased as needed, but remain between the minimum and maximum values set in the configuration. Note that not all apache threads will serve php files as some requests may be fetching static files, therefore you should always have more apache threads than php processes.

`Start Server` and `Start Threads` represents just the number of processes/threads created during the startup. This have almost no effect on performance since the number of threads will be immediately increased or reduced to fit the values of `Spare Threads`.

`MaxConnectionsPerChild` and `max_requests` are just the maximum amount of requests executed during the process/thread life. Unless you have memory leaks, you won't need to tune those values.

Comment: Thanks for this detailled answer. If I try to sumup, if I have php-fpm and apache process that don’t use cpu And my ram is not full —-> My config is OK, increase the different values will not decrease the response time —> I have to check something else. Sound good?

Comment: @LexaGC Yes, that's mostly it.